# Junit preconditions and test data

Tags: java, unit-testing, preconditions

I have a java assignment to create an address book then test and evaluate it. I have created it and created some junit tests. In the deliverables section of the assignment it says to list all the test cases for the full program in a table along with:

- A unique id
- a description of the test
- pre-conditions for running the test
- the test data
- the expected result

Could somebody tell me what they mean by the preconditions and the test data for the test below:

```
public void testGetName() 
{
    Entry entry1 = new Entry("Alison Murray", "34 Station Rd", "Workington", "CA14 4TG");
    assertEquals("Alison Murray",entry1.getName());    }
```

Tried emailing the tutor (im a distanct learner) but its taking too long to get a reply. Would the pre-condition be that entry1 needs populated? Test data: "Alison Murray"? Any help is apreciated

Comment: First thing to learn: use `assertEquals` rather than `assertTrue(x == y)`. Second thing to learn: don't use `==` for string equality.

Comment: Testing for string equality with `==` is generally bad. It's particularly dangerous because it works some of the time. Use `.equals`. Edit: argh beaten to it.

Comment: @robbie_c thanks guys, I have actually used assertEquals on other tests so why I have used assertTrue here I dont know. I'll change it over

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of checks with JUnit:

- assertions (`org.junit.Assert.*`);
- assumptions (`org.junit.Assume.*`).

Assertions are usually used to check your test results. If teh result is not what was expected, then the test fails.

Assumptions are used to check it test data are valid (if they match the test case). If they don't, the test is cancelled (without any error).

As I read your code sample: there are no preconditions and the test data would be `entry1`.